# Issues with multi-file selection and camera image import in Android web app

Tags: java, android

There is an issue I am not solving.

I'm a web developer and I'm tinkering with Android code.

Since I lack basic knowledge, I ask the developers for help.

1. The web app is shown through the web view, and you need to select and register multiple images among the parts that register the content.
2. There was no multi-select function in the existing Android code, so I put it through Google search.
3. So now multi-selection seems to work well.
4. However, as soon as I click 'OK' on the image file taken with the camera, the app is terminated.

This is the code I used and am modifying.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            Log.d(TAG, "***** onShowFileChooser()");
            //return super.onShowFileChooser(webView, filePathCallback, fileChooserParams);

            /* 파일 업로드 */
//            if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
//                //파일을 한번 오픈했으면 mFilePathCallback 를 초기화를 해줘야함
//                // -- 그렇지 않으면 다시 파일 오픈 시 열리지 않는 경우 발생
//                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
//                mFilePathCallback = null;
//            }
//            mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

            if (filePathCallbackLollipop != null) {
                filePathCallbackLollipop.onReceiveValue(null);
                filePathCallbackLollipop = null;
            }
            filePathCallbackLollipop = filePathCallback;

            boolean isCapture = fileChooserParams.isCaptureEnabled();
            runCamera(isCapture);

            //권한 체크
//            if(권한 여부) {

//             //권한이 있으면 처리
//             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
//             intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
//             intent.setType("*/*");  //모든 contentType 파일 표시
// //            intent.setType("image/*");  //contentType 이 image 인 파일만 표시
//             startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            return true;
        }
..............
 private void runCamera(boolean _isCapture) {
            Intent intentCamera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
//        intentCamera.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            File path = getFilesDir();
            File file = new File(path, "picture.png"); // sample.png 는 카메라로 찍었을 때 저장될 파일명이므로 사용자 마음대로
            // File 객체의 URI 를 얻는다.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                String strpa = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
                cameraImageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), strpa + ".provider", file);
            } else {
                cameraImageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            }
            intentCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, cameraImageUri);

            Intent fileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            fileIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            fileIntent.setType("*/*");  //모든 contentType 파일 표시
            fileIntent.setType("image/*");  //contentType 이 image 인 파일만 표시

            if (!_isCapture) { // 선택팝업 카메라, 갤러리 둘다 띄우고 싶을 때
                Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                pickIntent.setType(MediaStore.Images.Media.CONTENT_TYPE);
                pickIntent.setData(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                pickIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true); // 멀티 다중 선택을 지원하기 위해 추가

                String pickTitle = "사진 가져올 방법을 선택하세요.";
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickIntent, pickTitle);

                // 카메라 intent 포함시키기..

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
                    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_LOLLIPOP_REQ_CODE);
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Parcelable[]{ fileIntent });
                    return;
                } else {
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Parcelable[]{ intentCamera, fileIntent });
                    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_LOLLIPOP_REQ_CODE);
                }
            } else {// 바로 카메라 실행..
                int PERMISSION_ALL = 3;
                String[] PERMISSIONS = {
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                };

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
                    return;
                }
                startActivityForResult(intentCamera, FILECHOOSER_LOLLIPOP_REQ_CODE);
            }
        }
....................................

 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
//        switch (requestCode) {
//            case FILECHOOSER_NORMAL_REQ_CODE:
//                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
//                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
//                        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, data));
//                    } else {
//                        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(new Uri[]{data.getData()});
//                    }
//                    mFilePathCallback = null;
//                } else {
//                    if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
//                        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
//                        mFilePathCallback = null;
//                    }
//                }
//                break;
//            default:
//                break;
//        }

        Log.d("requestCode: ", String.valueOf(requestCode));
        Log.d("resultCode : ", String.valueOf(resultCode));

        switch (requestCode) {
            case FILECHOOSER_NORMAL_REQ_CODE:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    if (filePathCallbackNormal == null) return;
                    Uri result = (data == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK) ? null : data.getData();
                    //  onReceiveValue 로 파일을 전송한다.
                    filePathCallbackNormal.onReceiveValue(result);
                    filePathCallbackNormal = null;
                }
                break;
            case FILECHOOSER_LOLLIPOP_REQ_CODE:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    if (filePathCallbackLollipop == null) return;
                    if (data == null)
                        data = new Intent();
                    if (data.getData() == null)
                        data.setData(cameraImageUri);

                    filePathCallbackLollipop.onReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, data));
                    filePathCallbackLollipop = null;
                } else {
                    if (filePathCallbackLollipop != null) {   //  resultCode에 RESULT_OK가 들어오지 않으면 null 처리하지 한다.(이렇게 하지 않으면 다음부터 input 태그를 클릭해도 반응하지 않음)
                        filePathCallbackLollipop.onReceiveValue(null);
                        filePathCallbackLollipop = null;
                    }

                    if (filePathCallbackNormal != null) {
                        filePathCallbackNormal.onReceiveValue(null);
                        filePathCallbackNormal = null;
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:

                break;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this answer: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15341. With multiple files, you need to use `result.data.clipData`.

```kotlin
val returnedValue: Array<Uri>? =
  if (result.resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    null
  } else if (data?.clipData != null) {
    // The files are in data.clipData if the user selected multiple files
    // https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15341
    val clipData = data.clipData!!

    (0 until clipData.itemCount).map { clipData.getItemAt(it).uri }.toTypedArray()
  } else {
    WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(result.resultCode, data)
  }
```